# Windows keep changing position when disconnect and reconnect monitors

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors

I'm  on a windows 8 laptop and I have two external monitors I hook up to it. Whenever I take the laptop somewhere (and have to disconnect my monitors), the windows all go to my small laptop screen, naturally.

Its super annoying to reposition every single window every time i reconnect. When I reconnect my monitors, I'd like the windows to appear back where they were before I disconnected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a small tool to handle that. It is not complete but I'm receiving positive feedback and still working on it.
It is free, you have source code (C++), you may compile it with Cygwin and there are binaries if you don't compile C++ code.

You may find it here: https://github.com/manutalcual/winredock

Comment: This works fantasticaly! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Are you expecting to be able to go from two external displays, one internal display, then back to two external displays, and restore the windows positions?  If so, you'll need to use a third-party utility to save window positions and restore them.

[WinSize2](http://winsize2.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) should do what you want.  Others have mentioned AutoHotKey scripts and AutoIT as well.

Comment: That looks pretty cool. I'll check that out later : )

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I can't figure out how I would save an load the positions of my windows. There is a clear option for saving and loading desktop icon positions, but it doesn't look like that's even working.

Comment: Cursory inspection of the page suggests you'll want to use the Extras-2 tab, and define different INIs depending on the Screen Resolution.  Not exactly convenient, but doable.

Answer (score 1):

This answer mentions AutoResizer, which is a huge step forward in helping me maintain sanity: [Windows utility to save/restore window size & position history?](https://superuser.com/questions/71248/windows-utility-to-save-restore-window-size-position-history)

Answer (score 1):

[How to stop windows resizing when the monitor display channel is turned off / switched to different source](https://superuser.com/questions/267086/how-to-stop-windows-resizing-when-the-monitor-display-channel-is-turned-off-sw/878366#878366)
I recommend PersistentWindows which *just works* also very convenient on RDP sessions with different resolutions remote desktop connection.